# Laravel automatize routes

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I am using some routes in my laravel App like this:

```
Route::get('/structure', 'Superuser\StructureController@index');
```

So if I go to localhost/myproject/structure I am using StructureController and it's method "index". 
Now I would like to use another features, like add, update, delete, reorder etc... 
Is there any simple way, that I needn't to write:

```
Route::get('/structure/add', 'Superuser\StructureController@add');
Route::get('/structure/update/{url}', 'Superuser\StructureController@update');
Route::get('/structure/delete/{url}', 'Superuser\StructureController@delete');
```

If is this possible, I would like to use ::get for everything. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use GET for everything i dont think there is a built in automated way to do it, though you could write a method that spits out routes based on a passed in controller name perhaps.

There is automated RESTful/Resourceful routes for resource controllers:

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

This would generate these routes:

```
Actions Handled By Resource Controller
Verb    URI                    Action   Route Name
GET     /photos                index    photos.index
GET     /photos/create         create   photos.create
POST    /photos                store    photos.store
GET     /photos/{photo}        show     photos.show
GET     /photos/{photo}/edit   edit     photos.edit
PUT/PATCH   /photos/{photo}    update   photos.update
DELETE  /photos/{photo}        destroy  photos.destroy
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What will I do, when I will need more of routes? I don't even know, why I would like to use GET for everything, perhaps is pretty simple to my needs. I don't understand laravel as well I think... :(

Comment: can always add more routes even if you use the Route::resource command. But if you dont know why you would use GET as opposed to POST, for example, that's more of a basic web application concept rather than laravel. Recommend you hadd your routes 1 at a time for now. GETS for addresses you want users to visit. POST for form submissions. Most basic you can get.

Comment: Hello. Sorry that I bother again. I tried your example above, but I am afraid it doesn't work. I'm getting error. Don't need to generate something with artisan? I have just written the "resource" with controller name to routes/web.php and doesn't work.

Comment: No dont need to do an artisan command for this. Why describe what your line of code is, rather than copy pasting it exactly? Would be much easier for someone to help u seeing actual line. And when you say doesnt work, are you getting an error? Likely you have a namespace problem.